# How to get filepath of called prototype method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following example:

*// MyType.js*

```
function MyType(){}
MyType.prototype.getFile = function(){
   return __filename;
}
```

*// SubType.js*

```
var util = require('util');
function SubType(){}
util.inherits(SubType, MyType);
```

*// test.js*

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    subtype = require('./SubType'),
    myObject = new subtype();

assert.equal(myObject.getFile(), '/some/path/SubType.js'); // currently it fails, obviously
```

I know `__filename` doesn't work that way, but I was hoping there's a alternate late binding version of `__filename` or something equivalent?

Comment: What is it you want subTypeInstance.getFile to return? You can extend getFile in the following way: `SubType.prototype.getFile=function(){var fn = MyType.prototype.getFile.call(this); return fn.toLowerCase();}` In this case SubType returns getFile of MyType but changes it to lower case. Did you mean to return `this.__filename`? Code provided never seem to set a global variable named __filename so it'll always return undefined.

Comment: The global: http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename. I know I could extend it and place "the same" code, but I don't want to repeat myself.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code return the correct fileName?

```
function MyType(){
  this.__fileName=__filename;
  //maybe some other code you want to re use in subtype(s)
}
MyType.prototype.getFile = function(){
   return this.fileName;
}
```

One thing I'm not sure of when you re use parent constructor if the fileName is still correct:

```
function SubType(){
  MyType.call(this);
}
```

Comment: I guess something like this would work, but there isn't another way without writing any extra code at the subtype? Using the trace maybe? I'm looking into this.

Comment: Yeah, I can't use the trace either, the intermediate subtype doesn't show up in it :/

Comment: @lucaswxp If that code doesn't work you can try `this.fileName=__filename` in the SubType constructor